# WebViewClient return data to Activity onPageFinished

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I need to collect browser cookies from a WebView and return them to another Activity. Collecting the cookies works already but happens within a class that extends `WebViewClient`, and I don't know how to return the data from there.

There are 2 Activities; MainActivity and LoginActivity, respectively. MainActivity has a single button that creates an Intent and starts LoginActivity, which has a single WebView. `OnCreate()`, the WebView is directed to the login page of a website. When the user successfully logs into this site, it stores data in the browser cookies - data that I need for an API call later. How can I return this data to MainActivity?

The WebView has a custom WebViewClient with an overridden `OnPageFinished()` method, which if the URL is the one expected, will collect the browser cookies, as shown below.

```
class TempWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // If page URL is the Home page (ie., you logged in successfully), collect cookies.
        if (url.equals("https://slate.sheridancollege.ca/d2l/m/home")) {
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            String[] cookies2 = cookies.split(";");
            String key1 = "";
            String key2 = "";

            // Find Keys placed in browser cookies.
            for (String c : cookies2) {
                String[] c2 = c.split("=");

                if (c2[0].equals(" phrase1")) {
                    key1 = c2[1];
                }
                if (c2[0].equals(" phrase2")) {
                    key = c2[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LoginActivity should not call `finish()` (returning to MainActivity) until I've received the keys from the cookies. How can I achieve this, given what I have already? I don't know how LoginActivity can hold off returning to MainActivity until it has the data from its WebView.

```
public class LoginActivty extends Activity {
    WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        setupViews();
        setContentView(webview);
    }
    public void setupViews() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        webview = new WebView(this);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new TempWebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("website");
    }
}
```

Comment: easy way you can store cookies in sharedPreference with some default value and check after login fininsh in main activity or startActivity for result, then return the result.

Comment: The problem is the timing; it looks like a multi-threading issue. I want LoginActivity to return to MainActivity ONLY when the cookie's key has been obtained.
Your solution doesn't account for time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create reference of login activity in TempWebclient to pass the result once you get your cookie.

```
class TempWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

  LoginActivty mDelegate;

  public TempWebViewClient(LoginActivty ref) {
         this.mDelegate = ref;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { 
   // perform task 
    String cookie;// get from CookieManager
    mDelegate.sendCookieAndFinish(cookie);
  }

}
```

Create function in your login activity

```
public class LoginActivty extends Activity {

    WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ....
    }
    public void setupViews() {
       ....
        // send activity reference to webclient
        webview.setWebViewClient(new TempWebViewClient(this)); 
    }

   public void sendCookieAndFinish(String cookie){
     setResult(ResultCode,ResultIntent); // set result for your main activity
    // store cookie to storage
    finish();
  }

}
```

From Main Activity start your LoginActivity for result